# Syntax error when using Curdate()

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Am trying to create a table containing a column which tracks the time when a row has been inserted.

The below query works fine. Creation of table is done and am able to view the date and time in the column *track_date* when data is added.

```
CREATE TABLE tracker(id int, track_date DATETIME DEFAULT NOW());
```

Suppose I now need to track just the date so I now run below query but I get syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE tracker_2(id int, track_date DATE DEFAULT CURDATE());
```

Can you please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) is quite clear on this point.  You can set the default for a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` column, but not for a date:

> This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date
>   column to be the value of a function such as `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE`.
>   The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default
>   for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns.

Your options are to use a trigger or to remove the time component when you query the column.

(I should note that the statement is a little misleading, because `NOW()` *can* be used as the default for a `DATETIME` as both the question and the documentation to clarify.  The paragraph is referring to `DATE` columns, in particular.)